# Skip a pattern from another matching pattern regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a R character vector whose elements are alphanumeric strings. Here is an example:

```
mystring <- c("_IT_GSL_WEL_71_71_71_71", "_UTTEW_1_LCL_ABE_GT_3MTHST",  "_UTTEW_3_LCL_ABE_GT_2MTHST")
```

What is needed is a regex that matches only letters up to and **excluding** the **first** number encountered, and, at the same time ignores the digit immediately after any `_UTTEW_` pattern.
The expected output should be: `c(_IT_GSL_WEL_`, `_UTTEW_1_LCL_ABE_GT_`, `_UTTEW_3_LCL_ABE_GT_)`. 
This is what I have until now

```
stringr::str_extract(mystring, pattern = "(^\\D*\\d)")
```

which does not skip the `_UTTEW_+digit` pattern as can be verified with the ouput produced

```
c("_IT_GSL_WEL_7", "_UTTEW_1", "_UTTEW_3")
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `I would like a regex`? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Does the pattern need to work for strings that start with `_UTTEW_#_` but *do not* have another number after that, such as `_UTTEW_3_LCL_ABE_GT_ABCD`?

Comment: Strings might (usually do) contain additional digits after the digit in `_UTTEW_#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try to do it in two steps:

```
new<-gsub("\\d[A-Z]{4,}","",mystring,perl=TRUE)
gsub("\\d{2,}_.*","",new)
#[1] "_IT_GSL_WEL_"         "_UTTEW_1_LCL_ABE_GT_" "_UTTEW_3_LCL_ABE_GT_
```

Comment: or may be `gsub("(_)((\\d+[A-Z_]+)|([0-9_]+))$", "\\1", mystring)`